# PhoneAuthProvider just started throwing error (possibly on simulator only)

Tags: ios, firebase-authentication

Out of nowhere, the `PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, uiDelegate: nil)` started failing on my simulator, but still works on my device (same build obviously).  I've tried both real phone numbers and testing phone numbers.

I'm on SDK version `9.6.0` and run it on an iOS 16.1 simulator.

Here's the error I'm getting:
`Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17048 "Token mismatch" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Token mismatch, FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=INVALID_APP_CREDENTIAL}`

Here's my `AppDelegate`:

```
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func userNotificationCenter(
        _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
        didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
        withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void
    ) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        
        completionHandler()
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .unknown)
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification notification: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(notification)
        
        if (Auth.auth().canHandleNotification(notification)) {
            completionHandler(.noData)
            return
        }
    }
}

extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
        let tokenDict = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
        
        NotificationCenter.default.post(
            name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"),
            object: nil,
            userInfo: tokenDict)
    }
}
```

Also here’s my Firebase certificates setup:
[image]

Any ideas?

EDIT: Now that I think about it, yesterday I updated my macOS to `13.0.1`. Could it have anything to do with it?

EDIT 2: It seems that it still works on an iOS 15 simulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, I finally nailed it : I updated Firebase to the latest version (10.2) and now it works on iOS 16 too :-)